# Error fechas classic asp y oracle

Tags: oracle, asp

Estoy teniendo un problema para realizar una inserción de una fecha y una hora en una base de datos. Estoy usando asp classic y la base de datos es oracle. El código que estoy usando es el siguiente

```
 Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
             conn.Open conexion
             sql = "insert into tabla ("
             sql = sql & "campo1,campo2,fecha_hora,campo3,campo4,campo5)"
             sql = sql & " values('"
             sql = sql & valor1& "','" & valor2 & "','" & now & "','" & valor3 & "','" & valor 4 & "','Cadena')"
             conn.Execute(sql)
```

Y al ejecutarlo me muestra el siguiente error:

> ```
> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
>
> [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01830: la máscara de formato de fecha termina antes de convertir
> toda la cadena de entrada
> ```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El formato de fecha de la aplicación es incompatible con el de la base de datos. Esto se puede corregir formateando o de una manera más simple si estás buscando almacenar la fecha y hora actual.

Podrías probar de la siguiente manera:

```
 Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
         conn.Open conexion
         sql = "insert into tabla ("
         sql = sql & "campo1,campo2,fecha_hora,campo3,campo4,campo5)"
         sql = sql & " values('"
         sql = sql & valor1& "','" & valor2 & "', sysdate,'" & valor3 & "','" & valor 4 & "','Cadena')"
         conn.Execute(sql)
```

con **sysdate** estarías almacenando la fecha y hora actual del servidor en tu campo.

Comment: Si me ha funcionado.Gracias por la ayuda.